# React + Material UI - Overriding MuiTheme in component withStyles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, higher-order-components

I am using [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) with React. Trying to override the `TextField` component style which has been setup using a global theme. I have setup a global theme for all `TextField` components in the app.

Relevant code:

`theme-engine.js`:

```
export const theme = brand => createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: Brand.getColors(brand).primary
        },
        secondary: {
            main: Brand.getColors(brand).secondary
        },
    },
    typography: {
        fontFamily,
        fontSize: 14,
        htmlFontSize: 16
    },
    overrides: {
        MuiInputBase: {
            root: {
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
                fontSize: '14px',
                fontFamily,
                '&:after': {
                    borderBottom: Brand.getColors(brand).primary,
                    backgroundColor: Brand.getColors(brand).primary,
                    height: 1
                },
                '&:focused:not($disabled):not($error):before': {
                    borderBottom: Brand.getColors(brand).primary,
                    backgroundColor: Brand.getColors(brand).primary,
                    height: 1
                },
                '&$error:before': {
                    borderBottom: '#f44336',
                    backgroundColor: '#f44336',
                    height: 1
                },
            },
        },
        MuiInput: {
            root: {
                fontFamily
            },
            underline: {
                '&:hover:not($disabled):not($error):not($focused):before': {
                    borderBottom: '#e0e0e0',
                    backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0',
                    height: 1
                },
                '&:not($disabled):not($error):after': {
                    borderBottom: Brand.getColors(brand).primary,
                    backgroundColor: Brand.getColors(brand).primary,
                    height: 1
                },
                '&$error:before': {
                    borderBottom: '#f44336',
                    backgroundColor: '#f44336',
                    height: 1
                },
                '&$error:after': {
                    borderBottom: '#f44336',
                    backgroundColor: '#f44336',
                    height: 1
                },
            },
        },
        MuiSvgIcon: {
            colorPrimary: {
                fill: '#74797b'
            },
            colorSecondary: {
                fill: Brand.getColors(brand).primary,
            }
        },
    }
});
```

`container.js`:

```
 render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme(brand)}>
                //stuff goes here
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
    }
```

Now in one of the components, I am using an icon for the `TextField` and want the underline to come under the icon as well. For that I am trying to override the provided theme, which isn't working. The styles from the `theme-engine` are applied, but the local override isn't working.

`some-component.js`

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const TextFieldIcon = withStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        underline: {
            color: 'red',
            height: 4,
            '&:before': {
                borderBottom: `1px solid #e0e0e0`,
                bottom: '-8px',
                left: '-32px'
            },
            '&:hover:not($disabled):not($error):not($focused):before': {
                borderBottom: 'red',
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                height: 1,
                bottom: '-8px',
                left: '-32px'
            },
            '&:not($disabled):not($error):after': {
                height: 2,
                bottom: '-8px',
                left: '-32px'
            },
            '&$error:before': {
                height: 1,
                bottom: '-8px',
                left: '-32px'
            },
            '&$error:after': {
                height: 1,
                bottom: '-8px',
                left: '-32px'
            },
        },
    }
}))(TextField);

class SomeComponent extends Component{
        //Lifecycle methods to make your life easier....or difficult.

        render(){
            return(
                <TextFieldIcon {...assign props and stuff} /> //Styles are not applied
            )
        }
}
```

So the question is, I want to keep the custom global theme, but also override some parts of it in my component. Any inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues:

- You should not have the `underline` rule nested under `root`. You should be able to just remove the outer `root` block
- In order to refer to other rules (e.g. `$disabled`, `$error`, and `$focused`), those rules need to be defined within the styles object you pass to `withStyles`
- The classes generated by `withStyles` are the classes for the `Input` component wrapped by `TextField`, so you need to pass them via the `InputProps` property

Below is a working example of the syntax you need. I have not tried to assess whether the styles are doing what you intend, but they are definitely being applied.

```
import React from "react";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const styles = theme => ({
  underline: {
    color: "red",
    height: 4,
    "&:before": {
      borderBottom: `1px solid #e0e0e0`,
      bottom: "-8px",
      left: "-32px"
    },
    "&:hover:not($disabled):not($error):not($focused):before": {
      borderBottom: "red",
      backgroundColor: "red",
      height: 1,
      bottom: "-8px",
      left: "-32px"
    },
    "&:not($disabled):not($error):after": {
      height: 2,
      bottom: "-8px",
      left: "-32px"
    },
    "&$error:before": {
      height: 1,
      bottom: "-8px",
      left: "-32px"
    },
    "&$error:after": {
      height: 1,
      bottom: "-8px",
      left: "-32px"
    }
  },
  disabled: {},
  error: {},
  focused: {}
});
const CustomTextField = ({ classes, ...other }) => {
  return <TextField InputProps={{ classes: classes }} {...other} />;
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomTextField);
```

[image: Edit Custom TextField]

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Your bullet points helped me understand more about how the `withStyles` HOC works.